# how to store the response from post api using react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

How we can store this response using react redux and display account number in next page using react redux.

```
{responseCode: "00", responseDesc: "Login successful",}
data: {accountNumbers: ["98765432102"], cifNumber: "87654"}
responseCode: "00"
responseDesc: "Login successful".
```

Comment: you should have to learn about `react-redux` from [this link](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: ok please share any coding related to this. if available